# Does retrbinary() and storbinary() in ftplib raise exception if transfer not successful?

Tags: python, ftplib

Do the `retrbinary()` and `storbinary()` functions in `ftplib` raise exceptions if transfer not successful (or do I need to explicitly check for this)?

Eg. I currently have code that does...

```py
ftp = ftplib.FTP(<all the connection info>)
try:
    fd = open(MYFILE, 'rb')
    res = ftp.storbinary("filename.csv", fd)
    print(str(res))
    fd.close
except:
    print("Failed to upload file")
```

I notice that 1) the `type` of the return value from `storbinary` is just a `str` and 2) it reads *"266 Transfer Complete"* when successfully uploaded file to the ftp location. If there is a problem during uploading, will the except section of the code get triggered **(ie. will the `storbinary` function throw an exception) OR do I need to explicitly check the string literal response** like...

```py
ftp = ftplib.FTP(<all the connection info>)
try:
    fd = open(MYFILE, 'rb')
    res = ftp.storbinary("filename.csv", fd)
    print(str(res))
    fd.close
    if str(res) is not "226 Transfer Complete":
        raise Exception
except:
    print("Failed to upload file")
```

...? Is there another more conventional way to catch this? (I have the same question for `ftplib`'s `retrbinary` function as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they will throw an exception, if they get an error response from the server or if the connection is lost unexpectedly.

*Though note that with FTP protocol, in some cases, it's not always possible to tell that the transfer has failed.*